# BISON - How to enter a complete input?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

How can I input a full statement for example `x = 2` instead of doing like:

```
input: x *enter*
input: = *enter*
input: 2 *enter*
```

?

Currently I manage to enter inputs on BISON but separately instead of just one statement. I get outputs from single inputs but when I try to enter all in one statement there is no output.

y file:

```
 %{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void yyerror(char *s);
int yylex(void);
int yydebug = 1;

%}




%union { char * stringValue;
        int integer;
        double real;
        char * string;

        char expresion;
 }

%start program

%token ASSIGNMENT
%token IF
%token THEN
%token END
%token PRINT
%token READ
%token REM
%token LOGICAL
%token ARITHMETIC
%token COMPARISON
%token ERRORTOKEN

%token <integer> INTNUMBER
%token <real> REALNUMBER
%token <stringValue> STRING

%token <string> INTTOKEN REALTOKEN STRINGTOKEN



%%

program:        /* empty */
                |
                program exp {;}
                ;

line:           stmt
                ;
exp:          INTTOKEN {printf("Token");}
            | INTNUMBER {printf("Number");}
            | ASSIGNMENT      {printf("Sign");}
            | INTTOKEN ASSIGNMENT INTNUMBER {printf("Assignment");}
            ;
stmt:       exp
            ;

%%

void yyerror (char *s) {fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);}


int main (void) {

  yydebug = 1;
  return yyparse();

}
```

Lex file:

```
    %{
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

%}

%%


=                                   return ASSIGNMENT;
if|IF                       return IF;
then|THEN               return THEN;
end\.|END\.             return END;
print|PRINT             return PRINT;
read|READ                   return READ;
rem|REM                     return REM;
\.gt\.                      return COMPARISON;
\.eq\.                      return COMPARISON;
\.lt\.                      return COMPARISON;
\.ge\.                      return COMPARISON;
\.le\.                      return COMPARISON;
\.ne\.                      return COMPARISON;
\.and\.                   return LOGICAL;
\.or\.                      return LOGICAL;
\.not\.                     return LOGICAL;
\.add\.                     return ARITHMETIC;
\.mul\.                     return ARITHMETIC;
\.div\.                     return ARITHMETIC;
\.sub\.                     return ARITHMETIC;
\".*\"                      { yylval.stringValue = yytext; return STRING; }
[0-9]+                      { yylval.integer = atoi(yytext); return INTNUMBER; }
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+          { yylval.real = atoi(yytext); return REALNUMBER;}
[a-fA-F][a-zA-Z]*       { yylval.string = yytext; return INTTOKEN; }
[g-nG-N]+[a-zA-Z]*      { yylval.string = yytext; return REALTOKEN; }
[o-zO-Z]+[a-zA-Z]*      {   yylval.string = yytext; return STRINGTOKEN; }
.*                                  ;
%%

int yywrap(void) {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Note that the parser generator is almost irrelevant here. It merely processes tokens returned by the lexer. The lexer is what's responsible for taking input characters and turning them into tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the `.*` to `.` and fixed. Really messy mistake of my part.